# How to prove or disprove the asymptotic normality of the following?

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Let $\{X_{1},\ldots ,X_{n}\}$ be a sequence of non independent random variables. For $i,j \in [n]$, given

\begin{align}
 E[X_{i}] &= 0.\\
\text{Var}(X_{i}) &= \sigma^2 <  \infty.\\
\text{Cov}(X_{i}, X_{j}) &= 0, \quad i \neq j.
\end{align}

Can we say something about the asymptotic normality of $X_{1}+ \ldots+ X_{n}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Any help or lead would be highly appreciated.

Comment: In what sense are these variables "dependent"?

Comment: @GordonSmyth, if we rearrange the sequence elements in the matrix form, the elements in any row or column are dependent.

Comment: If elements are independent when they *aren't* in the same row or column, that's enough for a central limit theorem https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-16/issue-1/Normal-Convergence-by-Higher-Semiinvariants-with-Applications-to-Sums-of/10.1214/aop/1176991903.full

Comment: @ThomasLumley Dear Prof. Thomas Lumey, Thanks for your prompt response. Yes, in our setting, we arrange random variables in the form of a matrix, and they are independent when they are neither in the same row nor in the same column. Would it be possible for you to point which theorem (in the paper mentioned by you in the above comment) addresses this. 

Apologies if I sound naive as I am a beginner in these concepts.